# AngularJS + WebAPI External Google Authentication

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, api

I am currently setting up an external login (Google) into my AngularJS WebApp which is talking to a Web API, all locally, however I am having issues.

I have followed the steps in http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services on how to set up google authentication, which involves in just adding `app.UseGoogleAuthentication();` without appId or clientSecret like other providers like Facebook.

Now going to my API I query and get all providers using following `GET /api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true` , which return `[{"Name":"Google","Url":"/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A11942%2F&state=E2eXxoZ02yUg39-DrwZTXHnrV5FrOhUe-k-zz-oD6uE1","State":"E2eXxoZ02yUg39-DrwZTXHnrV5FrOhUe-k-zz-oD6uE1"}]`

and from reading in the internet I stripped the URL `/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A11942%2F&state=E2eXxoZ02yUg39-DrwZTXHnrV5FrOhUe-k-zz-oD6uE1` and added into a anchor tag, so I suppose this should have redirected me to google authentication, however I receive a error message

[image]

Does anyone know why? Also when adding the link into an anchor tag I am adding the link for my API http://localhost:11942/ at the start.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to authenticate with google (Open ID) is deprecated, refer to:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/changes-to-google-oauth-2-0-and-updates-in-google-middleware-for-3-0-0-rc-release.aspx

You need to use Google OAuth, try to follow the following article to configure Google authentication:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#goog

Comment: Thank you for this. Now I am having a different issue. After the user has been authenticated it is directing them to the API, and I don't want this to happen, I want then to go back to my app http://localhost:8000 in this case. Do you know what to do?